# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec error with neo4j

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I am trying neo4j from java as follows:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
    import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;   
    public class tests {   
    public enum nodetype implements Label
    {
    Student,teacher;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbfactory=new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService graphdb =dbfactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Users\\Zigzago\\.Neo4jDesktop\\neo4jDatabases\\database-f308fc06-68df-4463-841d-fb3ab98b1b08\\installation-3.3.3\\data\\databases\\graph.db");
    try(Transaction tx=graphdb.beginTx())
    {  
    Node s= graphdb.createNode(nodetype.Student);
    s.setProperty("Pid",5001);
    tx.success();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    String message = ex.getMessage();
    }
    graphdb.shutdown();
    }    
    }
```

and pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4jtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

but I get the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project neo4jtest: Command execution failed. Process
>   exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

knowing that iam using netbeans8.1 with jdk : java version "1.8.0_144"

Comment: Could you `Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging`?

Comment: Sorry iam new to java but how to use maven with -X?

Comment: No idea ;) -- I don't actually know Java, I just sorta pretend to know what I'm doing.